# dynamically loading new content from asp.net mvc server using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a website which is indexing news from other news websites.
I have a asp.net mvc page that displays those news and it only displays 10 news on each page.

```
<div class="news">news content here</div>
```

and I am going to use pagination (page numbers at the bottom of the page to move between different pages).

I also want to implement ajax loading of new news that gets added to the database after the page has been loaded in the browser of the users.

Considering all that has been said:
1- how can I know which new news content should be loaded using ajax? How can I differentiate between already loaded content from database and those newly added content? how can ajax tell the server which news was already loaded? how can I implement this so that the server will only send new news contents to the client and not all of the records of those news in the database? (I don't want to load all of those 10 news items which are going to be displayed in the main page using ajax, I only want the newly added news items to be loaded using ajax.)

Any good methods for marking the lastly loaded content from the server?
Should I mark the lastly loaded content inside  tags using jquery, or should it be done in the server side and how?

Comment: is that a question or a user story ?

Comment: I edited the question to be more accurate.

Comment: Do you directly show the news or contents from other website or you save them in your application's database first?

Comment: I save them inside my own database and load from there

Comment: "how can ajax tell the server which news was already loaded?" By keeping track of what it's loaded, and when requesting content, sending a parameter which indicates that, perhaps the ID of the last item that it loaded, or something like that. All your other questions are, when you look carefully, essentially variants of that question. The only other thing you perhaps have to consider is how the server decides what the first set of data to be sent should be. This probably depends on your definition of "new", which you haven't shared.

Comment: do you want the updated news to keep updating at given intervals (polling)?
if not then you need to use websockets to push data from server to client page. without which only option you have is to poll data with ajax at some fixed interval.
then you are talking about paging too.. now how do you expect the paging to behave when you are talking about updating news items when there is new content. this behaviour make no sense.

Comment: I have gave up pagination for the moment